# Instagram API: Cannot get media by hashtag

Tags: python, api, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to build a python app that fetches media posted with a certain hashtag and processes it in some way.

The problem is that using `v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent` I can get only my user's photos for some reason.

How can I get all photos from any users with the certain hashtag?

Comment: To troubleshoot whether your code might be missing something or whether Instagram might have a limitation, you could compare making the same query with the upstream Instagram Python API: https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram

Comment: @cr3 i was using this lib :)